# Connection Error in Mongo DB in Windows

Tags: mongodb

I am super new in doing MongoDB. Today is my first time doing it. The MongoDB is setup by someone else before that so I need some help here.

I tried starting mongo and this is the error:

```
C:\MongoDB>mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.12
connecting to: test
2017-05-05T17:36:18.459+0800 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 
127.0.0.1
:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2017-05-05T17:36:18.459+0800 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to 
server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

I also tried starting mongod.exe and there is error. Not sure if it's interlink or not.

```
C:\MongoDB>mongod.exe
2017-05-05T17:52:42.543+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : 
pid=2
1708 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=xxxx
2017-05-05T17:52:42.544+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 
7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2017-05-05T17:52:42.545+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.12
2017-05-05T17:52:42.545+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 
ef3e1bc78e997f0d9f22f45aeb1d8e3b6ac14a14
2017-05-05T17:52:42.545+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: 
OpenSSL1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016
2017-05-05T17:52:42.546+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-05-05T17:52:42.546+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-05-05T17:52:42.546+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-05-05T17:52:42.546+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 
2008plus-ssl
2017-05-05T17:52:42.547+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-05-05T17:52:42.547+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: 
x86_64
2017-05-05T17:52:42.547+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-05-05T17:52:42.548+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in 
initAndListen: 29 Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating
2017-05-05T17:52:42.548+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

I did see that data\db is created but just not in C:\ .In the config file, there is already a path written.

```
systemLog:
path: D:\MongoDB\mongod.log
storage:
dbPath: D:\mongod\data\db
```

Comment: Can you try running it as an administrator in terminal?

Comment: Yes, I did run as administrator

Answer (score 1):

By default, `mongod` will attempt to use `\data\db` on the drive which you start MongoDB as its [dbpath](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-dbpath). In your case, that's `C:\data\db`.

If you'd like to start `mongod` as configured by the previous person (including access to its data), you need to provide option [--config](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-config) to [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#mongod) to point to the configuration file. This will set `mongod` to use the config file and run according to the setup provided (as configured by the previous person). i.e. using `D:\data\db`.

See also: [Run MongoDB Community Edition (Windows)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#run-mongodb-community-edition) and [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#the-mongo-shell)

Answer (score 0):

After add inbound rule for tcp 27017 port at firewall
you should add the external IP Adress into config file,
[mongod.cfg]

```
        # network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, add external ip here
```

Answer (score -1):

I had that problem too. In my case, I start mongodb server first 
Here what i did

- open cmd as administrative
- type ***net start MongoDB***
- then type ***mongo***

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: the directory is missing per log entry